# Android Kotlin How to update content in current activity on FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging

The scenario is when user open chat activity and after that a firebase chat data notification is received. Code below,

```
class myFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        // how do i update chat content here?
        // startActivity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will restart the activity
        // startActivity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT will crash the app
        // or is there a way to call a method in chat activity to update it's content?
    }
}
```

How do i update chat content in the currently openned chat activity/screen?

Comment: Send broadcast from service to activity or simply insert content into database and observe in activity using Room / ObjectBox (rxJava or LiveData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener in the chat activity, that is notified when notification is received

create new file:

```
class NotificationReceivedListener {

    var listener: OnNotificationReceivedListener? = null

    interface OnNotificationReceivedListener{
        fun onNotificationReceived(bundle: Bundle?)
    }

    fun setOnNotificationReceivedListener(param: OnNotificationReceivedListener) {
        listener = param
    }

    fun notificationReceived(bundle: Bundle?){

        listener?.let {
            it.onNotificationReceived(bundle)
        }
    }

}
```

in FirebaseMessagingService companion object:

```
var notificationReceivedListener = NotificationReceivedListener()
```

in onMessageReceived:

```
notificationReceivedListener.notificationReceived(payloadBundle)
```

in activity:

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService.notificationReceivedListener.setOnNotificationReceivedListener(object :
NotificationReceivedListener.OnNotificationReceivedListener {
                    override fun onNotificationReceived(args: Bundle?) {
                          activity!!.runOnUiThread( {...})
            }
```

Comment: With this way is it only chat activity can receive the event? I have other activity which needs to update based on message received from FirebaseMessagingService too.

Comment: @Eddi no, any activity can call the listener

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddi keep us updated

Comment: Hi Sharone, has error on WDFirebaseMessagingService.notificationReceivedListener. Is it supposed to be an instance of myFirebaseMessagingService? How do I get the instance of myFirebaseMessagingService in chat activity's onCreate event?

Comment: yes you just call MyFirebaseMessagingService.notificationReceivedListener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208230/discussion-between-eddi-and-sharone-lev).